# How to access fields of JSON object return by the API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I am trying to display the response returned by the API. I am able to display the whole API response but am unable to display the particular field of the object.

API used is: https://lichess.org/api/user/nihalsarin2004

Response is:

```
{
  "id": "nihalsarin2004",
  "username": "nihalsarin2004",
  "online": false,
  "perfs": {
    "chess960": {
       "games": 107,
       "rating": 2574,
       "rd": 102,
       "prog": 79
 },
"antichess": {
  "games": 158,
  "rating": 1923,
  "rd": 109,
  "prog": -37
},
"atomic": {
  "games": 4434,
  "rating": 2381,
  "rd": 63,
  "prog": -20
},
"racingKings": {
  "games": 78,
  "rating": 1962,
  "rd": 110,
  "prog": 48,
  "prov": true
},
"ultraBullet": {
  "games": 14270,
  "rating": 2415,
  "rd": 45,
  "prog": -8
},
"blitz": {
  "games": 917,
  "rating": 2912,
  "rd": 68,
  "prog": 35
},
.
.
.
.
"puzzle": {
  "games": 436,
  "rating": 2429,
  "rd": 97,
  "prog": 0
},
"classical": {
  "games": 0,
  "rating": 1500,
  "rd": 500,
  "prog": 0,
  "prov": true
},
"rapid": {
  "games": 0,
  "rating": 1500,
  "rd": 500,
  "prog": 0,
  "prov": true
},
"storm": {
  "runs": 68,
  "score": 109
},
"racer": {
  "runs": 3,
  "score": 129
},
"streak": {
  "runs": 1,
  "score": 4
}
},
"createdAt": 1505668328682,
"profile": {
  "country": "IN",
  "firstName": "Nihal",
  "lastName": "Sarin"
 },
"seenAt": 1628540487222,
"patron": true,
"playTime": {
"total": 2527288,
"tv": 1064938
},
"language": "en-US",
.
.
.
.
"followable": true,
"following": false,
"blocking": false,
"followsYou": false
}
```

You can check FULL API response also on the link given above.

I am fetching the data from API , although I am able to access `username` of above response by like this:

```
async function lichessProfile(username) {
    await fetch(`https://lichess.org/api/user/${username}`)
    .then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((json) => setData(json));
}
```

And accessing the `username` like this :

```
 let username =  JSON.stringify(data.username);
```

And using it in my react component as:

```
<div>
    <br/>
        Name : {username} 
    <br/>
</div>
```

But If I want to access the Rating in blitz, I am using this & getting error:

```
let blitzRating = JSON.stringify(data.perfs.blitz.rating);
```

I am getting error while using above line ,
[image]

Although I am able to access using the same code in console.[image]

Do anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: Use parse? That's funny.

Comment: The data was stringified before it was sent over API to you, just parse the data, so it's seen as an accessible object. Try this, let ParsedData = JSON.parse(data); Then console.log(ParsedData.perfs.blitz);

Comment: Also use question mark so it avoids errors when object does not exist like this: let blitzRating = JSON.stringify(data?.perfs?.blitz?.rating);

Comment: by the way it blitz is not inside perfs so  let blitzRating = JSON.stringify(data?.blitz?.rating);

Comment: @blanknamefornow I am using this but still getting error
     let pr = data.perfs;
     let blitzData = pr.blitz;
     let blitzRating = JSON.stringify(blitzData.rating);

I am using it as  {blitzRating} in component

Comment: Yeah you're using JSON incorrectly.

Comment: Also added the JSON.parse but still I am getting error @blanknamefornow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with your code.

1. You don't have to use the `stringify` method. Just `let username =  data.username;`
2. The problem you are encountering related to **React Component Lifecycle**

- Because `linchessProfile` component will render itself and all its' sub-component, before the function fetching data from the API in `lichessProfile` component get called.
- When `lichessProfile` rendering itself, you tell the component to get data in the fetched result, which has not fetched data yet, the same with getting data inside  `undefined`.

=> Solution: You can code like this for everytime you try to ***read fetched data***:

```js
let blitzRating = data?.perfs?.blitz?.rating ?? "";
```

**Note**: You should read about *React Component Lifecycle*, *React Hooks*, *Optional chaining*, *Nullish coalescing operator*

Comment: Can you clarify what the solution code actually does?

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 `?.` was called *optional chaining*, `??` was called *Nullish coalescing operator*. When the code tries to access `data` properties (like `perfs`) and if `data.perfs` is equal to `undefined` or `null`, value *empty string* will be assigned to `blitzRating` variable, the same with nothing when displaying. If `data` is *empty* object, (`data = {}`), so `data.perfs` equal to `undefined` then `data.perfs.blitz` will raise the same error in this question. Add `?.` to `data?.perfs?.blitz` will auto assign `undefined` value to the variable instead of raising an error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us when you use `let blitzRating = JSON.stringify(data.perfs.blitz.rating);` please. I think you use it before the data is processed.

Note that You don't have to use the `stringify` method. Just `let blitzRating = data.perfs.blitz.rating;`

Comment: I use it in the React component after name . Like as 

Blitz Rating : {blitzRating}

Comment: There are 3 ways to not render component if there aren't any data yet.

`{data && <Component data={data} />}`
Check `if(!data) { return null }` before render. This method will prevent All component render until there aren't any data.
Use some `<Loading />` component and ternar operator inside JSX. In this case you will be able to render all another parts of component which are not needed data -> `{data ? <Component data={data} /> : <Loading>}`

Comment: check here : [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/nokwiw/project/editor/XwyKyr)